# How to check if an object property of a collection is not empty (deep level) - Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I have this collection of Product types

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1388
  #items: array:3 [
    0 => App\Model\ProductType {
      #attributes: array:7 [
        "id" => 3
        "type" => "GG"
        "businessId" => 22
        "created_at" => "2020-09-17 00:00:00"
        "updated_at" => "2020-09-17 00:00:00"
      ]
    }
    1 => App\Model\ProductType {
          #attributes: array:7 [
        "id" => 1
        "type" => "Personal Collection"
        "businessId" => 22
        "created_at" => "2020-09-17 00:00:00"
        "updated_at" => "2020-09-17 00:00:00"
      ]
    }
    2 => App\Model\ProductType {
      #attributes: array:7 [
        "id" => 2
        "type" => "Supplies"
        "businessId" => 22
        "created_at" => "2020-09-17 00:00:00"
        "updated_at" => "2020-09-17 00:00:00"
      ]
}
```

And `ProductType` model has `getProductsAttribute` which has condition that products will be only included if it has variants and variants will we only included if its stocks is > 0

---

Here is my sample code:

---

```
$checkProductsWithVariants = Product::where('productTypeId', $this->id)->get();

$variantStocksCount = 0;
   foreach ($checkProductsWithVariants as $product) {
       $variantStocksCount += $product->variants->count();
   }

$hasProduct = $variantStocksCount > 0 ? true : false;
```

***Take note that i'm running this for every productType***

> My problem is if I have many product types and products. my code is slow.

***I want to know if there's a way to check like this or something similar to avoid looping every single products just to check variant's stocks***

```
ProductType::where('product.variants.stocks', '>', 0);
```

Comment: Do you tried with this https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence? You can use the querying existence how has or whereHas

Comment: I think it's for relationships only. not appends